# Mechanism of synthesis of allene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, allenes

> [image]

I would like to know the mechanism of this reaction. In my first attempt to the question, I had replaced the two $\ce{Br}$s by $\ce{CH3}$s by $\ce{S_N2}$ of the organometallic compound but the answer given was the above allene. I think my reaction isn't possible because of too much hindrance. So if that's the case, then what is the mechanism of the actual reaction?

Comment: Lithium-halogen exchange

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely redox with rearrangement.

Comment: Just to be more explicit, replace one of the bromides with a lithium, i.e., a carbanion. Then, you should be able to draw a rearrangement that gives the allene.

Comment: @Waylander How to identify if lithium halogen exchange takes place in a particular reaction?

Comment: In this case it is because you have not added any carbons to the molecule. MeLi is not a great nucleophile for alkyl halide in general, principally because lithium-halogen exchange is an alternative pathway.

Comment: @Waylander Page 2  [here](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/76432/1/chd050_4_450.pdf) shows carbene formation for this reaction, I am not able to understand what happens after that. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @abcd The simplest way to view the process is that one eq of MeLi reacts with the dibromide by Li-Hal exchange to give a carbanion at the carbon still bearing the second Br. This Br then leaves as Br- creating the carbene.

Comment: Note that the paper referenced states  " Tetra-substituted   allenes   can  not  be  prepared   by  the  reaction   of  tetraalkyldibromocyclopropane and   methyl   lithium. "

Comment: @Waylander Then, how are we proceeding with this reaction if tetra substituted allenes cannot be prepared by tetraalkyldibromocyclopropane + MeLi?

Comment: The OP asked about carbene formation. The carbene forms, but inserts in a C-H bond to form a bicyclobutane rather than collapse to the allene.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [Skattebøl rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skatteb%C3%B8l_rearrangement), the first step is of which is a [lithium-halogen exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organolithium_reagent#Lithium-halogen_exchange) to form a carbenoid. A mechanistic study of the rearrangement of monosubstituded lithium bromocyclopropylidenoids found that allene formation can occur either in a concerted (**Scheme 2**) or step-wise (**Scheme 3**) fashion depending on the ability of the substituent to stabilize the intermediate carbene$^{[1]}$.

> [image: Schemes]

The study found that electron donating groups (like the methyl groups in your example) lower the barrier to allene formation. For several EDG-substituted species, the free carbene structure **14** could not be found as an energy minimum and all attempts to locate these structures lead directly to allenes. This means the stepwise mechanism does **not** play a role in the Skattebøl rearrangement for EDG-sbustituded species$^{[1]}$.

---

<sup>$[1]$ [Azizoglu, A.; Balci, M.; Mieusset, J.-L.; Brinker, U. H. *The Journal of Organic Chemistry* **2008**, *73* (21), 8182–8188.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo8011144)</sup>