# 1,1-Dibromo-2,2,3,3-tetramethylcyclopropane is treated with CH3Li

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

My approach:
The ring is extremely sterically hindered. And also due to ring strain ring gonna break .
Here methyl lithium ($\ce{CH3Li}$) acts as a base so it is going to take the most acidic hydrogen and then I drew like this but getting no way out there.

[image]

Comment: duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99317/mechanism-of-synthesis-of-allene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this review paper [1](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/76432/1/chd050_4_450.pdf) the answer is d - none of these

The reaction proceeds by initial lithium-halogen exchange followed by carbene formation. In some cases the allene (answer c) is formed but, as stated in the paper referenced, tetra-alkyl dibromocyclopropanes give bicyclobutanes by insertion of the carbene into one of the methyl C-H bonds.

This is further discussed in this posting [Mechanism of synthesis of allene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99317/mechanism-of-synthesis-of-allene)